# How to Send Message From AlertDialog to Activity

Tags: java, android, interface, dialog

I'm trying to ask the user if he wants to retry a login process if the initial one has failed.
I do this using an AlertDialog. The problem is i'm going around in a circle. Let me explain:
I have the login method named Login which I call from the main activity. If this fails, I open an AlertDialog. The response from AlertDialog comes on the main thread. How do I make the AlertDialog dissapear before I call Login again?

Now I have something like this onCreate->Login->AlertDialog->ResponseHandler->Login. If I do this, the AlertDialog will never close because everything happens on the same thread.

Is there a way to send the response from the AlertDialog to the activity in a asynchronous way?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `Handler` object as an anonymous inner class in your activity and on its reference call the `sendEmptyMessage(0)`. in the `handlerMessage()` of the handler instance just dismiss the `AlertDialog`.

Here is a tutorial link which will help you more https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html